# How to reuse layouts/layout-attributes and change single attributes afterwards

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this simple button XML:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/some_color" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

And I use it like so:

```
<Button
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonxml"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="String"
    android:id="@+id/button"/>
```

Problem is, by doing so the only color I can have with this button XML is some_color. If I want to reuse this same layout, I'll need to create another XML to just change the color. Is there somehow I can reuse the button XML, changing only some values? I was thinking in something like:

```
<Button
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonxml"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="String"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    parent:color="@color/anotherColor"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a Custom Button style in your `styles.xml` to reuse specific styles:

```
<style name="CustomButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/buttonxml</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

You can use this style in you layouts:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="String"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    style="@style/CustomButtonStyle"  
    />
```

The `textColor` will be white and the  the `background` will be `buttonxml`.

---

If you want to overwrite singe attributes just add it to yout layout. They will overwrite the style (the Theme style and the style in the layout)

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="String"
    style="@style/CustomButtonStyle"  
    android:textColor="@color/anotherColor"


    />
```

Here the `textcolor` will be `anotherColor` but the `background` will still be `buttonxml`.

**Alternative**

Use [include](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) to reuse a whole layout. You can also overwrite attributes if you add them in the include.

```
<include android:id=”@+id/news_title”
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textColor="@color/anotherColor"
     layout=”@layout/yourbuttonlayout”/>
```